# python regular expression error

Tags: python, regex

I am trying do a pattern search and if match then set a bitarray on the counter value.

```
runOutput = device[router].execute (cmd)
            runOutput = output.split('\n')
            print(runOutput)
            for this_line,counter in enumerate(runOutput):
                print(counter)
                if  re.search(r'dev_router', this_line) :
                    #want to use the counter to set something
```

Getting the following error:

> if  re.search(r'dev_router', this_line) :
>
> 2016-07-15T16:27:13: %ERROR:   File
>   "/auto/pysw/cel55/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 166,
>
> in search 2016-07-15T16:27:13: %-ERROR:     return _compile(pattern,
>   flags).search(string)
>
> 2016-07-15T16:27:13: %-ERROR: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the arguments for [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) - first goes the index, then the item itself. Replace:

```
for this_line,counter in enumerate(runOutput):
```

with:

```
for counter, this_line in enumerate(runOutput):
```

---

You are getting a `TypeError` in this case because `this_line` is an integer and [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) expects a string as a second argument. To demonstrate:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> this_line = 0
>>> re.search(r'dev_router', this_line)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

---

By the way, modern IDEs like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) can detect this kind of problems statically:

[image]

(Python 3.5 is used for this screenshot)

Comment: And then the counter can be something simple as: before loop `counter = 0`, and if matched `counter += 1`